# Spark DStream from Kafka always starts at beginning

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

**Look at my last comment of the accepted answer for the solution**

I configured a `DStream` like so:

```
  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "kafka1.example.com:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer],
    "group.id" -> "mygroup",
    "specific.avro.reader" -> true,
    "schema.registry.url" -> "http://schema.example.com:8081"
  )

  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, DataFile](topics, kafkaParams)
  )
```

While this works and I get the `DataFile`s as expected, when I stop and re-run the job, it always starts at the beginning of the topic. How can I achieve that it continues where it last went off?

## Follow up 1

As in the answer by Bhima Rao Gogineni, I changed my configuration like this:

```
val consumerParams =
  Map("bootstrap.servers" -> bootstrapServerString,
      "schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryUri.toString,
      "specific.avro.reader" -> "true",
      "group.id" -> "measuring-data-files",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer],
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: JavaBool),
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest")
```

And I set up the stream:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.
  createDirectStream(ssc,
                     LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
                     ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, DataFile](List(inTopic), consumerParams))
```

And then I process it:

```
stream.
  foreachRDD { rdd =>
    ... // Do stuff with the RDD - transform, produce to other topic etc.
    // Commit the offsets
    log.info("Committing the offsets")
    val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
    stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)        
  }
```

But it still always starts from the beginning when re-running.

Here is an excerpt from my Kafka log:

A run:

```
[2018-07-04 07:47:31,593] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group measuring-data-files with old generation 22 (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:47:31,594] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group measuring-data-files generation 23 (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:47:31,599] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader for group measuring-data-files for generation 23 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:48:06,690] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=data-0] Writing producer snapshot at offset 131488999 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2018-07-04 07:48:06,690] INFO [Log partition=data-0, dir=E:\confluent-4.1.1\data\kafka] Rolled new log segment at offset 131488999 in 1 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-07-04 07:48:10,788] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-07-04 07:48:30,074] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member consumer-1-262ece09-93c4-483e-b488-87057578dabc in group measuring-data-files has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:48:30,074] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group measuring-data-files with old generation 23 (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:48:30,074] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group measuring-data-files with generation 24 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:48:45,761] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=data-0] Writing producer snapshot at offset 153680971 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2018-07-04 07:48:45,763] INFO [Log partition=data-0, dir=E:\confluent-4.1.1\data\kafka] Rolled new log segment at offset 153680971 in 3 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-07-04 07:49:24,819] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=data-0] Writing producer snapshot at offset 175872864 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2018-07-04 07:49:24,820] INFO [Log partition=data-0, dir=E:\confluent-4.1.1\data\kafka] Rolled new log segment at offset 175872864 in 1 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
```

Next run:

```
[2018-07-04 07:50:13,748] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group measuring-data-files with old generation 24 (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:50:13,749] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group measuring-data-files generation 25 (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:50:13,754] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader for group measuring-data-files for generation 25 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:50:43,758] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member consumer-1-906c2eaa-f012-4283-96fc-c34582de33fb in group measuring-data-files has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:50:43,758] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group measuring-data-files with old generation 25 (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-07-04 07:50:43,758] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group measuring-data-files with generation 26 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-8) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

## Follow up 2

I made saving the offsets more verbose like this:

```
    // Commit the offsets
    log.info("Committing the offsets")
    val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
    if(offsetRanges.isEmpty) {
      log.info("Offset ranges is empty...")
    } else {
      log.info("# offset ranges: %d" format offsetRanges.length)
    }
    object cb extends OffsetCommitCallback {

      def onComplete(offsets: util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata],
                     exception: Exception): Unit =
        if(exception != null) {
          log.info("Commit FAILED")
          log.error(exception.getMessage, exception)
        } else {
          log.info("Commit SUCCEEDED - count: %d" format offsets.size())
          offsets.
            asScala.
            foreach {
              case (p, omd) =>
                log.info("partition = %d; topic = %s; offset = %d; metadata = %s".
                  format(p.partition(), p.topic(), omd.offset(), omd.metadata()))
            }
        }
    }
    stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges, cb)
```

And I get this exception:

```
2018-07-04 10:14:00 ERROR DumpTask$:136 - Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:600)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:541)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:679)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:658)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:426)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:278)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitPendingRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:222)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.ensurePartitionAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:366)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:978)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.paranoidPoll(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:334)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:121)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With new Spark Kafka Connect API, We can try async commits.

Read the offsets and commit once done with the process.

Kafka config for the same:

`enable.auto.commit=false`

`auto.offset.reset=earliest` or `auto.offset.reset=latest` --> this config takes effect if there is no last committed offset available in Kafka topic then it will read the offsets from start or end based this config.

```
 stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

   // some time later, after outputs have completed
   stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}
```

Here is the source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. It still starts from the beginning.

Comment: I edited my original question to include my investigations.

Comment: stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

   // some time later, after outputs have completed
   stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}

Comment: can you try printing the offset and some data, so that we can see whether it starts from the same offset or not? How much is the batch duration? After starting the job wait at least for 1 or more batches to process and kill the job and start it.

Comment: Your answer indeed works. I just needed to set a higher value for `group.max.session.timeout.ms` in my `server.config` and a higher `session.timeout.ms` in my job config. Background: The job listens for file names of created measuring data files on one topic, and when they arrive, kicks off a batch job to produce these to another topic. This can take longer than the default of 30s and caused the error.

Comment: Nice and happy for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Spark provides two APIs to read messages from kafka.

From Spark documentation

> #### Approach 1: Receiver-based Approach
>
> This approach uses a Receiver to receive the data. The Receiver is implemented using the Kafka
>   high-level consumer API. As with all receivers, the data received from
>   Kafka through a Receiver is stored in Spark executors, and then jobs
>   launched by Spark Streaming processes the data.
>
> #### Approach 2: Direct Approach (No Receivers)
>
> This new receiver-less “direct” approach has been introduced in Spark
>   1.3 to ensure stronger end-to-end guarantees. Instead of using receivers to receive data, this approach periodically queries Kafka
>   for the latest offsets in each topic+partition, and accordingly
>   defines the offset ranges to process in each batch. When the jobs to
>   process the data are launched, Kafka’s simple consumer API is used to
>   read the defined ranges of offsets from Kafka (similar to read files
>   from a file system).
>   
>  **Note that one disadvantage of this approach is
>   that it does not update offsets in Zookeeper**, hence Zookeeper-based
>   Kafka monitoring tools will not show progress. However, you can access
>   the offsets processed by this approach in each batch and update
>   Zookeeper yourself

In your case you are using Direct Approach, so you need to handle your message-offset yourself and specify the offset range from where you want to read the messages. Or if you want zookeeper to take care of your message-offset then you can use Receiver-based Approach by using `KafkaUtils.createStream()` API.

You can find more on how to handle kafka offset in  [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html).

Comment: This is true for the 0.8 Kafka Integration library. I am using the 0.10 one, and as per [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#storing-offsets) it stores offsets periodically. Maybe I didn't wait long enough. I try disabling auto commit and committing manually as described in [this blog post](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2017/07/31/how-to-achieve-exactly-once-semantics-in-spark-streaming/)